# didInsertElement in Ember 2.0+

Tags: ember.js

**Ember.View** is deprecated, in favor of **Components**. That's great but I'm having trouble making sense of the 2.0 release.

Most often, I used the `didInsertElement` hook to run some jQuery code etc. But now that the `Em.View` class has been deprecated, how can I achieve the same thing? I don't want to create a component or anything like that. It doesn't make sense to create components for normal pages(routes). Simply because its not a re-usable thing plus component's scopes are isolated.

Say we have a about route, and when the template is rendered I just want to sun some jQuery code. How can I do this in Ember 2.0+?

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of `didTransition` hook and `Ember.run.next`. Check my solution:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    didTransition() {
      Ember.run.next(this, 'initParticles');
    }
  },
  initParticles() {
    let ammount = (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 456px)').matches) ? 40 : 100;
    particlesJS('particles-js', {
      // my options
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank Daniel, this works well too. Now that Views are deprecated, is it OK to keep such codes in the route file?

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't seem like the best approach, creating a component is probably your best option. Soon we'll have routeable components which will take over much of what controllers and views use to do. Creating a component and just inserting it into your template should put you on a good path to be ready for routeable components.